# Find a number of photos inside a photo album

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have photo albums and their photos stored in Neo4j. I would like to be able to find one album and get a certain amount of photos. The goal is to lazily load photos as required (pagination).

Now I can do the following to achieve what I want:

```
match(p:Photo)-[bt:BELONGS_TO]->(a:Album) where a.name = "Summer 2019" return a, collect(p)[..4] as photos
```

However I would like to be able to sort the list of photos by different criteria such as their upload date or creation date. I'm not exactly sure whether this is the best approach to do this.

```
match(p:Photo)-[bt:BELONGS_TO]->(a:Album) where a.name = "Summer 2019" return a, collect(p)[4..] as photos order by p.file_name
```

Fails and tells me the following:

> In a WITH/RETURN with DISTINCT or an aggregation, it is not possible to access variables declared before the WITH/RETURN: p

I would like to keep the exact same format of the result (one album, one page of photos) if possible so that I don't have to do complicated mapping inside my application code:

```
╒══════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"a"                   │"photos"                                                              │
╞══════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Summer 2019"}│[{"file_name":"cat.jpeg"},{"file_name":"dog.jpeg"},{"file_name":"birdi│
│                      │e.jpeg"},{"file_name":"bird.jpeg"}]                                   │
└──────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

**Is there a clean way to get this format while being able to sort the photos?**

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `[4..]` (instead of `[..4]`, as used in your first query)? It seems strange that you would want to order the photos by `file_name` but only get the results starting at the 5th one.

Comment: Good catch! I was editing the query while posting this question so it might've slipped in there that way. Should've copied & pasted the first query with [..4] :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ORDER BY before collecting your `p` nodes

```
MATCH (p:Photo)-[bt:BELONGS_TO]->(a:Album) 
WHERE a.name = "Summer 2019" 
WITH
    a,
    p
ORDER BY p.file_name
RETURN a, collect(p)[4..] as photos
```